# Will `async with` containing multiple statements execute them synchronously?

Tags: python, sql, asynchronous, async-await, with-statement

I'm using `aiosqlite` library and am wondering if the following code will execute inserts in order or asynchronously?

```
async with (
    db.execute("INSERT ..."),
    db.execute("INSERT ..."),
):
    pass
```

I'm guessing in order?

Comment: Um... yes to which one? :)

Comment: `async with` awaits each context manager's `__aenter__` method, so it will process them in order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Barmar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) comment, they will indeed execute in order.